# Can't make an application to copy text

Tags: java

I am trying to make an application that copy specific text from a website and give it to me in the output.

For Example; To visit www.sheeel.com and copy the Product name and price.

Anyone can help?

```
package posts;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Posts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] options = {"Kuwait", "KSA", "Exit"};
        int selected = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Which Website?", "Website", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        int linkN = 0;
        String link = null;
        String dealName;

        if (selected == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you");
        }

        if (selected < 2) {
            while (selected == 0) {

                Object[] options2 = {"Main Deal", "Special Corner", "Under 5", "Coupons", "Exit"};
                int web = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Which Category?", "Category", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options2, options2[0]);

                if (web == 0) {
                    link = "www.sheeel.com";
                }
                if (web == 1) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/special-corner.html";
                }
                if (web == 2) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/under-5-kd.html";
                }
                if (web == 3) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/coupons-kwt.html";
                }
                if (web == 4) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                dealName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deal Name:");

                String price;
                price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Price:");

                System.out.println("شيييل," + " " + dealName + "," + "فقط بـ" + " " + price + " " + "من " + " " + link);

            } //while end

            while (selected == 1) {

                Object[] options2 = {"Main Deal", "Special Corner", "Under 5", "Coupons", "Exit"};
                int web = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Which Category?", "Category", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options2, options2[0]);

                if (web == 0) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/ksa/";
                }
                if (web == 1) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/ksa/special-corner-192.html";
                }
                if (web == 2) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/ksa/under-99.html";
                }
                if (web == 3) {
                    link = "http://www.sheeel.com/ksa/cards-ksa.html";
                }
                if (web == 4) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                dealName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deal Name:");

                String price;
                price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Price:");

                System.out.println("شيييل," + " " + dealName + ", " + "فقط بـ" + " " + price + " " + "من " + link);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you try to access the website that is selected. What have you tried?

Comment: You should take a look at [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). [EXAMPLE](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url)